# Convert Two Strings -> PublicKey & Base64 encrypt it

Tags: java, encryption, base64, rsa, steam

So I am trying to connect to a website service (Steam) which requires the program to have a Base64 encrypted key which contains the password of the account which I am trying to logon to. I have the RSA key but am having a little difficulty encrypting it with the password. Here is my code:

```
if(jsonObject.getBoolean("success")){
        String timeStamp = jsonObject.getString("timestamp");
        String publickey_mod = jsonObject.getString("publickey_mod");
        String keyexp = jsonObject.getString("publickey_exp");
        String modulus_preHex = new BigInteger(1, publickey_mod.getBytes("UTF-8")).toString(16);
        String exponent_preHex = new BigInteger(1, keyexp.getBytes("UTF-8")).toString(16);
        BigInteger modulus_post = new BigInteger(modulus_preHex);
        BigInteger exponent_post = new BigInteger(exponent_preHex);
        PublicKey key = getEncrpytedKey(modulus_post, exponent_post);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] passArray = pass.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String encode = Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(passArray)).toString();
        System.out.println(encode + " - encode");


    }
```

This takes place after a successful POST to the URL where I retrieve the RSAKEY (publickey_mod) and when it expires (keyexp). After ciphering the PublicKey I Base64 encode the string.

```
    public PublicKey getEncrpytedKey(BigInteger m, BigInteger e) throws Exception{
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
        return pubKey;
}
```

^^^The method seen being used to get the PublicKey.

When I run this program, the 'encode' String does not change, **even when I change the password that is it running with**, it is currently:

String encode = `[B@32d992b2`

When the RSAKey is `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`

Note that I am not really well versed with encryption, as this is one of my first times trying it out.

Thanks for any help,
Tim

**NOTE**: I am using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;` for Base64.

Comment: base64 is an encoding and is not encryption...

Comment: @LukePark like I said, this is one of the first times that I have tried to do something like this so the terminology is not up to par xD. Do you see any other problems with the code?

Answer (score 0):

`Base64.encodeBase64` returns a `byte` array so what you want is

```
encode = new String (Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(passArray));
```

Comment: Okay I did this and was able to fix the 'encode' string not changing, but it is still not letting me login to the steam service because the passkey is not encrypted correctly. Do you see any other problems with the code?

Comment: sorry I have no idea about the steam service login.

Comment: Even without knowledge of the steam service, can you make sure that I am correctly:

1) Converting the modulus and exponent into a hex, then putting them into RSAPublicKeySpec as longs

2) Adding the password to the PublicKey and converting that whole thing into Base64

Comment: This looks wrong `new BigInteger(1, publickey_mod.getBytes("UTF-8")).toString(16);` What constructor do you think you are using?  Try using a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: I am trying to recreate the 'long(rsa_response['publickey_mod'],16)' method that is in python. Which basically turns the String into a hex decimal and returns a long. Because (to my knowledge) you cannot do the same with the long in Java. I tried to use BigDecimal to get the same effect. I am not entirely sure what the first parameter does, but the second is (hopefully) converting the byte[] into a hex string.

Comment: nah I think you just want `BigInteger(val).toString(16);`